Any way to keep the cards always inside the background image?
I want the cards to remain inside of the background image no matter of the screen size, and it's not working with me.
Here's my content code
{% block content %}
    <style>
        .custom-skills-section {
            background: url('{{ background_image }}') center center / contain no-repeat;
            border-radius: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1600px;
            height: 1200px;
        }

        .custom-skill-card-shadow {
            height: 150px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .custom-skill-card-content {
            border-radius: 8px;
            box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            background-color: #f0f4f8;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .custom-skill-title {
            font-size: 1em;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #333;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="min-height: 100vh;">
        <div class="custom-skills-section">
            <h2 class="text-center text-white py-4">My Skills</h2>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    {% for skill in skills %}
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 mb-4 custom-skill-card">
                            <div class="custom-skill-card-shadow">
                                <div class="custom-skill-card-content">
                                    <h4 class="custom-skill-title">{{ skill.name }}</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}

Hello,
I'm my idea is to put the cards inside the note board to appear like old school. but the cards always get out from the note board. on smaller screens they get out from up and down of the background image.
See how it looks on this image:


Set Max size for background and then where you have the cards, set them to change size accordingly with min and max and try and use a grid layout, also place everything in the same DIV always helps to keep everything in the same place

How wide do you want the cork board to be in relation to the viewport - and/or are there maximum and minimum sizes you want it to have?

If you want to keep the cork board as a background-image rather than an img, you will need to know its aspect ratio.

something like this should help you. Play with values of css to get what you expect exactly.
<style>
.custom-skills-section {
    background: url('{{ background_image }}');
    height:100%;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    margin:5%;
    overflow:scroll;
}

.custom-skills-section h2 {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
}

.custom-skill-card {
    width:33%;
}

.custom-skill-card-shadow {
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding:1rem;
}

.custom-skill-card-content {
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #f0f4f8;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.custom-skill-title {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.row {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
</style>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="custom-skills-section">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>My Skills</h2>
            <div class="row">
            {% for skill in skills %}
                <div class="custom-skill-card">
                    <div class="custom-skill-card-shadow">
                        <div class="custom-skill-card-content">
                            <h4 class="custom-skill-title">{{ skill }}</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


you can try this your CSS style:
.container{
  max-width: 95% // so that it will be never in outside the box and make 
                 sure it is less than 100%
}
.custom-skills-section {
 //your existing
 background-size: cover; 
}

Note: For Card , use Grid display
